# Can I submit a Mac App without enabling Sandboxing?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

As I heard that Mac Apps submitted must enable sandboxing. Because I want to use `NSRunningApplication.terminate`, and it doesn't work with sandboxing.

Answer (score 3):

Only sandboxed Apps are allowed, I'm sorry

UPDATE

Now Apple has extended the deadline for non sandboxed apps on the MAS until June. Apps that are not sandboxed can be updated even after that date... I think that is great news

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, you can submit a non-sandboxed app until March 1, 2012.  After that date, Apple will only accept sandboxed apps.

I'm not sure if they will remove non-sandboxed apps from the store once they are already in though.  They'll either remove them or prevent you from updating until you use entitlements.

Comment: Non-sandboxed apps will remain in the AppStore after this date. I've even read of exceptions that updates may be accepted, but you'll have to explain why you're submitting an update that's not sandboxed.